# Typescript - Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) after null check

Tags: typescript, syntax-error

I'm getting Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) after null check. Can someone help me with it? Am I doing something wrong?

```
    let array_of_some_data: ({ some_value: number } | null)[] = [];

    //Getting Object is possible 'null' error as expected. Because I didn't check null before trying to access value.
    array_of_some_data[0].some_value = 5;

    //Not getting error as expected since I've checked null this time.
    if (array_of_some_data[0] !== null) array_of_some_data[0].some_value = 5;
    
    //Why am I getting Object is possible 'null' error here? Only difference from above line is I've stored index value in a const.
    const x: number = 0;
    if (array_of_some_data[x] !== null) array_of_some_data[x].some_value = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a limitation with typescript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Currently, we can use literals such as `0` to narrow the type of an object (or, in this case, an array). However, we can't use constant variables such as `x` to do this. Typescript's developers decided not to implement this due to performance concerns.

There is an open PR discussing this issue in greater detail. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36230)

One workaround gives typescript a hand by using an intermediary assignment:

```
const x: number = 0;
var element_of_some_data = array_of_some_data[x];
if (element_of_some_data) element_of_some_data.some_value = 5;
```

Alternatively, use the `!` operator to tell typescript that we know the value isn't null:

```
const x: number = 0;
if (array_of_some_data[x] !== null) array_of_some_data[x]!.some_value = 5;
```